# How to display the email in View page of Drupal7

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

[image: View Page]

Suggest me how the edit page email Id make it to view in [view page] in Drupal7

Answer (score 0):

Copy the file /modules/user/user-profile.tpl.php to your theme's templates folder, then customize it with your needs.

You can dump the $user variable there, e.g.

```
<div class="profile"<?php print $attributes; ?>>
  <?php print render($user_profile); ?>
  <?php var_dump($user); ?>
</div>
```

The email address value is $user->mail.

Don't forget to run "drush cc theme-registry" after any edits to theme.

Answer (score 0):

```
function alt_user_view($account) {
 global $user;
  $account->content['email']['display'] = array(
  '#type' => 'user_profile_item',
  '#title' => t('E-mail Id:'),
  '#markup' => $account->mail . l(' (edit)', 'emailedit/' . $user->uid . '/' ),
  '#attributes' => array('class' => array('field-label')),
  '#weight' => 10,
   );

 }
```

i got the solution by this way. Is it ok.

Answer (score 0):

Another option to do it from custom Module compared to doing it from custom Theme (custmize the template which I had suggested) is implementing the hook_user_view_alter, you can refer to the document at https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.api.php/function/hook_user_view_alter/7.x

Also a third option mentioned in the document is implementing another hook called hook_preprocess_user_profile(), but the hook should be in custom Theme.

So it all up to you to whether do it with Module or Theme, with Theme hook or Theme template. Happing working with Drupal.